# Export SQL query results into a multi tabbed Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, db2, export, export-to-excel

I want to write a set of 100 select queries in DB2 10.1 to return all rows in each table in the database and have the results exported to an excel spreadsheet with a new tab for each result set.

Is this possible and if so how can I do it?

At the moment the only way I can do this looks like to export each result set and then manually create the multi tabbed spreadsheet by copying each tab across.

Thanks

Comment: Many scripting languages (python for example) have api's against both db2 and excel. I suggest you write a script in such language that automates the job. Creating 100 sheets manually sound both boring and error prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com) API for Excel with scripting languages like VB Script.
The VBS code should be similar with this one:

```
'The class that exports result set to Excel file
 Set xls = CreateObject("EasyXLS.ExcelDocument")

' The class used to format the cells
Dim xlsAutoFormat 
set xlsAutoFormat = CreateObject("EasyXLS.ExcelAutoFormat")
xlsAutoFormat.InitAs(AUTOFORMAT_EASYXLS1)

For query = 1 To 100

   ' Add a new sheet
   xls.easy_addWorksheet_2("Sheet" & query)
   set xlsSheet = xls.easy_getSheetAt(query - 1)

   ' Create the record set object
   Dim objResultSet
   Set objResultSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 
   objResultSet.Open queryString, objDBConnection

   ' Create the list that will store the values of the result set
   Dim lstRows 
   Set lstRows = CreateObject("EasyXLS.Util.List")

  ' Add the header to the list
  Dim lstHeaderRow 
  Set lstHeaderRow = CreateObject("EasyXLS.Util.List")
  lstHeaderRow.addElement("Column 1")
  lstHeaderRow.addElement("Column 2")
  lstHeaderRow.addElement("Column 3")
  lstRows.addElement(lstHeaderRow)

  ' Add the values from the database to the list
  Do Until objResultSet.EOF = True
     set RowList = CreateObject("EasyXLS.Util.List")
     RowList.addElement("" & objResultSet("Column 1"))
     RowList.addElement("" & objResultSet("Column 2"))
     RowList.addElement("" & objResultSet("Column 3"))
     lstRows.addElement(RowList)

     ' Move to the next record
     objResultSet.MoveNext
  Loop 

  xlsSheet.easy_insertList_2 lstRows, xlsAutoFormat

Next

' Export result sets to Excel file
xls.easy_WriteXLSFile("c:\Result sets.xls")
```

Check also this link about [exporting lists of data to Excel](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/export-list-to-excel.html).

If you will choose a non scripting language, the API has methods that insert data directly from the result set and the lists can be skiped. Check another sample [here](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/export-dataset-to-excel.html).